# evento do button em React.JS

Tags: react, chartjs

eu quero adicionar o grafico ao painel quando eu clicar no botão de acesso, como eu faço apra ele aparecer dentro do painel que eu estilizei sem colocar ele direto lá, só depois de clicar no button accessos???

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import { Bar } from 'react-chartjs-2'

import { Container, Graficos, Gerar } from './styles'

// Components
import SectionTopBar from '../../components/SectionTopBar'
import NavigationBar from '../../components/NavigationBar'

const Dashboard = () => {

  const access = () => {
    //MANDAR ADICIONAR A FUNÇÃO CHART() AQUI
  }

  const [charData, setCharData] = useState({})

  const chart = () => {
    setCharData({
      labels: ['Jorge', 'Lucas', 'Ana', 'Antonio', 'Luiza', 'Matheus', 'Luana'],
      datasets: [
        {
          label: 'Acessos',
          data: [25, 30, 13, 9, 47, 10, 21],
          backgroundColor: [
            'rgba(6, 196, 131, 0.4)'
          ],
          borderColor: [
            'rgba(6, 196, 131, 1)'
          ],
          borderWidth: 1
        }
      ]
    })
  }

  useEffect(() => {
    chart()
  }, [])

  return (
      <Container>
        <Graficos>

          <Gerar>
            <button className="card" onClick={access} >
              <div className="content-info">
                <text className="textbtn" >Acessos</text>
                <text className="quantidade" >12.000</text>
              </div>
              <div><i class="fas fa-sign-in-alt"></i></div>
            </button>

              <a></a>
            </button>
          </Gerar>

          <div className="grafico-container" >
             //ADICIONAR AQUI NO PAINEL
            <div className="painel" ><Bar data={charData} /></div>
          </div>

        </Graficos>
      </Container>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Nesse caso o ideal seria uma renderização condicional. Quando uma variável no seu programa for `true`, renderizar o gráfico.

Podemos fazer isso com o hook `useState` do React.

```
const Dashboard = () => {
  // Variáveis que vão armazenar o estado da página (Se o gráfico deverá ser mostrado ou não)
  const [displayChart, setDisplayChart] = useState(false);

  // Função para mostrar o gráfico ao clicar no botão
  const showChart = () => setDisplayChart(true);

  const chartData = {
    labels: ["Jorge", "Lucas", "Ana", "Antonio", "Luiza", "Matheus", "Luana"],
    datasets: [
      {
        label: "Acessos",
        data: [25, 30, 13, 9, 47, 10, 21],
        backgroundColor: ["rgba(6, 196, 131, 0.4)"],
        borderColor: ["rgba(6, 196, 131, 1)"],
        borderWidth: 1,
      },
    ],
  };

  return (
    <div>
      ... Conteúdo da página
      <button onClick={showChart}>Acessos</button>
      {/* Renderização condicional - Se a variável displayChart for "true" o gráfico será renderizado */}
      {displayChart && <Bar data={chartData} />}
    </div>
  );
};
```